# view did load but not viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I have two view controllers: `BSViewController` and `BSotherViewController`. `BSViewController` has a button on it that is segues to `BSotherViewController`. That part works fine and I can see the one VC and then the "other" VC when I run on the simulator. But I have an `NSLog(@"other");` in `BSotherViewController`'s `-viewDidLoad` which is not showing in the console. A similar `NSLog(@"other");` in `BSViewController`'s `-viewDidLoad` which is showing in the console. I suspect the problem is the lack of an `IBAction` but I cannot figure where it should go and how it should be linked in the storyboard.

BSViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BSViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number;
@end
```

BSViewController.m

```
#import "BSViewController.h"

@interface BSViewController ()
@end
@implementation BSViewController
@synthesize number;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.number = 25;
    NSLog(@"number: %d", self.number);
}

@end
```

BSotherViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BSotherViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger anumber;
@end
```

BSotherViewController.m

```
#import "BSotherViewController.h"
#include "BSViewController.h"
@interface BSotherViewController ()

@end

@implementation BSotherViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"other number:");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    BSViewController *view = [[BSViewController alloc] init];
    self.anumber = view.number;
    NSLog(@"other number: %d", self.anumber);
}
```

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Hey Zero, an easy solution would be to just use the ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear, it is not gaurenteed that the ViewDidLoad will be called everytime... it is likely being called in BSViewController because when you launch the app to the simulator it runs it fresh and therfore needs to load the view. Sometimes using modal segues and things it is not nessicary to call viewDidLoad....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storyboard is the second view controller set up as a `BSotherViewController`?  You can verify by hovering over the view controller icon in the storyboard.

[image: hovering]

If it's not, then click it and go to the identity controller and type it in.

[image: identity]

Comment: Now I can work on the real problem: Why is `other number` 0 instead of 25?  Great diagnosis, Mr Rogers.

Comment: It's because `BSViewController`'s view has not been loaded yet.  The initialization of 25 happens in `viewDidLoad`.  You can verify it by logging the view controller's `view` property right before you log `anumber`.